# Embedding Kotlin Library with Layout XML File in Flutter with Platform Channels

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter

Using platform channels, we can create factories and return native views in Flutter. What I'm trying to do is achieve this without using factory method, using XML layout files. Trying to implement this [CalendarView](https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView) library written in Kotlin. (for example, implement example 4 in `sample` directory)

I have considered using `LayoutInflater` method. Could `LayoutInflater` be used to achieve this? I would be appreciated if you can give me any tutorials or pseudo codes.